python numpy array index set extension
import numpy as np 

I = np.array([3,2,1,4,2])
x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
y = np.empty(5)
for i, j in enumerate(I):
    y[i] = x[j:].sum()

This is a simplified version of the original code. The problem is that the length of I is larger, so using loop is costly. Is there any way to avoid loop here?
I wish that I have something like
y = x[I:].sum()


You could use broadcasting to form a mask:
np.where(np.arange(len(x))>=I[:, None], x, 0).sum(1)

Output:
array([4.66666667, 4.88888889, 5.        , 4.33333333, 4.88888889])

